# page not found django.views.static.serve

Tags: python, django, filefield

first post so be gentle.

I am trying to display a static image in django. I can upload the image to my media directory but when I try to display it I get a nothing.  If I copy the url to the browser I get ...

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Will_and_Matt.jpg
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

detail.py

```
...
<img src="{{ student.photo.url }}" class="img-responsive">
...
```

model.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField( blank=True, null=True)
```

project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^opencmis/', include('opencmis.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My update form works as it created the media folder and places images in it.

The URL pattern seems to match /media as it doesn't give an error there it just doesn't display the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: `document_root=settings.STATIC_URL` should be [`document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) and similar for `MEDIA_ROOT`. You want the filesystem path in there, not the URL.

Comment: You Sir, are a gent. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

`document_root=settings.STATIC_URL` should be `document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT` and similar for `MEDIA_ROOT`. You want the filesystem path in there, not the URL.

– dhke